# How is Vertex Equality Defined? CLRS Shortest Paths

Tags: algorithm, graph

I'm currently going through CLRS and had a quick question. How is Vertex Equality defined? I'm having an issue with [image: context1] and [image: context2]. Does u != v imply that u and v are not adjacent? I thought it just implied that u and v aren't referring to the same vertex? Can't it be possible that u and v are adjacent and so there is no intermediate vertex w? Thanks guys.

Comment: You're correct. Variables are just that. They can stand for anything they're defined to represent.  If we know only that u and v refer to vertices, then they may be the same vertex unless u != v is explicitly stated. Similary a path u->w->v can have 1, 2, or 3 vertices (0, 1, or 2 edges) unless there are specific inequalities given.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is implied about adjacency. The text explicitly states that the intermediate vertex may be u or v. They've just chosen a confusing definition of "intermediate" vertex, where the intermediate vertex is allowed to be one of the endpoints of the path.

Answer (score 1):

A vertex is an entity on its own. A vertex is equal with itself. We can assign variables to vertices, and compare them (in the mathematical sense, the only defined comparison is equality, unless some order is assigned on the vertices).

In the book, a graph is defined as `G=(V,E)`, i.e. is a pair of:

- a set of vertices, `V`
- a set of edges, `E` (an edge is defined as a pair of vertices, i.e. elements of `V`).

You need to pick 2 elements of `V`, namely `u` and `v` and compute the shortest path between them. If you pick the same vertex twice, i.e. `u=v`, then the problem is trivial: the shortest path from a place to itself is empty, since you're already at the destination. The authors try to remove this trivial case by making the assumption that the vertices `u` and `v` are different.

You can think about vertices by assigning identifiers to each vertex. It is common, especially for implementation purposes, to assign unique numerical identifiers to each vertex. The vertex equality translates in this case to identifier equality.